# How to set the fixed height of the container inside the GridView.builder? should not depending on childAspectRatio

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]Actually I am trying to show a list of products inside the GridView.builder, but it's height changing as per childAspectRatio as per different devices of different heights. I want to fix them for every device...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and ended up calculating the `childAspectRatio` so that each cell ends up having the height that I want.

```
double cellWidth = ((MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - allHorizontalPadding) / columnCount);
double desiredCellHeight = 200;
double childAspectRatio = cellWidth / desiredCellHeight;
```

Comment: allHorizontalPadding means   
padding: EdgeInsets symmetric(horizontal: 7.0,vertical: 10.0) 
7 in this case right?|
but still it's not getting fixed hieght of card inside gridView In All Devices..

Comment: It's important to calculate the correct value for `allHorizontalPadding`. For example in your image above, that would be left padding (7) + right padding (7) + padding between grid cells (?)

Comment: crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 7.0, vertical: 10.0),
So I have added 24 in  allHorizontalPadding but still not able to fix height of card inside the GridView..

Comment: Are you sure you haven't missed something? Is the image above accurate ? Your crossAxisSpacing is visually smaller than the horizontal padding, in the image above. Is the resulting height consistently smaller or consistently larger than the desired one? (use the Flutter Inspector to find the exact height). Do you have dynamic padding or grid properties based on screen size?

Comment: please checkout code here, if something is wrong..let me know

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code - would you be able to show some screenshots demonstrating the difference across different screen sizes while using this approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207633/discussion-between-zeeshan-ansari-and-ovidiu).

Comment: Thanks ! issue solved now. enjoy your bounty reward :-)

Answer (score 0):

To do something like this you may want to use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

You will be able to adapt the layout more easily, otherwise with the GridView you have no choice you have to use `childAspectRatio`.

You can use it with `MediaQuery` properties to achieve a good design on every devices.

Comment: I have tried with that package and with MediaQuery also, but not getting the desired result, not able to fix container size inside gridView...

Comment: Ok but there's no real way to do that right now, you can look at @Ovidiu solution that uses the `MediaQuery`, which is the most suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Create something like this

First of all create a list of array class and override build method

```
class Products extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductsState createState() => _ProductsState();
}

class _ProductsState extends State<Products> {
  var productList = [
    {
      'name': "Blazzer",
      "picture": "images/products/blazer1.jpeg",
      "old_price": 120,
      "price": 85,
    },
    /*{
      'name': "Blazzer",
      "picture": "images/products/blazer2.jpeg",
      "old_price": 120,
      "price": 85,
    },*/
    {
      'name': "Red Dress",
      "picture": "images/products/dress1.jpeg",
      "old_price": 120,
      "price": 85,
    },
    /* {
      'name': "Blazzer",
      "picture": "images/products/dress2.jpeg",
      "old_price": 120,
      "price": 85,
    }*/
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: productList.length,
        gridDelegate:
            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return SingleProduct(
            productName: productList[index]['name'],
            productPicture: productList[index]['picture'],
            productOldPrice: productList[index]['old_price'],
            productPrice: productList[index]['price'],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

and create the above class like below

```
class SingleProduct extends StatelessWidget {
  final productName;
  final productPicture;
  final productOldPrice;
  final productPrice;

  const SingleProduct(
      {this.productName,
      this.productPicture,
      this.productOldPrice,
      this.productPrice});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Hero(
        tag: productName,
        child: Material(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ProductDetails(
                      //Passing Product details to another activity
                      productDetailName: productName,
                      productDetailNewPrice: productPrice,
                      productDetailOldPrice: productOldPrice,
                      productDetailPicture: productPicture,
                    ))),
            child: GridTile(
                footer: Container(
                  color: Colors.white70,
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Text(
                      productName,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    title: Text(
                      "\$$productPrice",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      "\$$productOldPrice",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Image.asset(
                  productPicture,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```